# Conditionally Inserting another record in a mailmerge document depending on a value in the next record

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-word, mailmerge

## The Situation

I maintain a legacy MS-Access database which is used to manage the contacts to a set of doctors offices. Initially the table "offices" (old) included information about the office and the employed doctors like this (abbreviated):

| office | street | number | postcode | city | name1 | surname1 | name2 | surname2 | name3 | surname3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

An office could have between 1 and 3 doctors.

### Initial Steps

A new requirement came up which asked for the separate modelling of offices and doctors as a 1:n Relationship.

I created a new table doctors:

| name | surname | office_id |
| --- | --- | --- |

transformed the underlying data, dropped the redundant fields from the "office"-table and am now in the process of modifying the buisness logic accordingly.

### First idea: Elegant or lazy? It fails any way

My first impulse was to create an "office" view which recreated the old "office" table and change the references to the "old" office table to this "office" view. This way I could keep the logic as it is and only adjust as needed.

The problem was, that the "office" table is very fundamental and used all over the place and i didn't manage to recreate the table without writing my own functions using a cursor making the view very costly. That the database is used in a Network environment didn't help because although this worked in principle, the .accdb file blows up to 70 to 80mb resulting in massive load times, making it in effect unusable.

### Lets do it properly

So I ditched the "office" view and reworked the database to employ the new data model. A MailMerge Letter is given me particular trouble and i haven't found a good solution yet. The DataSource for the MailMergeDocument is a View relying basicly on the data in the "offices" and "doctors" table.

#### The issue

previously the Address field in word just used this as a datasource

| id | street | postcode | city | name1 | surname1 | name2 | surname2 | name3 | surnname3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Mainstreet | 01234 | timbuktu | Doe | John | Mae | Jane | Bar | Foo |

Now i have an 1:n relationship and the datasource looks like this:

| office_id | street | postcode | city | surname | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Mainstreet | 01234 | timbuktu | John | Doe |
| 3 | Mainstreet | 01234 | timbuktu | Jane | Mae |
| 3 | Mainstreet | 01234 | timbuktu | Foo | Bar |

However i still need to get all 3 (or in other cases just 2 or 1) Doctors on the adress field and yes there can be more than 1 office listed in the datasource.

#### Possible Solutions

I see basicly 2 Options:

1. Transform the view back into the previous format, without using Custom Functions, making it costly again, using a Single SQL-Statement.
2. Using the field functions within the word document to skip through the records as needed.
   In theory the [Nextif-function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/field-codes-nextif-field-5dd7bd9c-29b1-4ef2-aba8-4f0387e8b417) should do exactly that, however i haven't been able to figure out how and if I can evaluate Data between different records in the word document.  I need something like:

`Nextif nextrecord.id = currentrecord.id`

but i havent found a way to reference the records whithin the fieldfunctions.

Any suggestions for a clean solution are welcome.

Regards

Comment: Possibly use VBA to concatenate all the names to a single string. Allen Browne's ConcatRelated function is one example. http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html

Answer (score 0):

As is so often the way, after spending all this time posing my question, i have found a way to tackle the problem. I thought about solution 1 recreating the old table format without the use of VBA and came up with a lean way to do it.

## The idea

If my doctors where numbered per office like this is doc no 1 in office no 6 etc i could simply count to three in the office table and refer to this unique DocID in a Join.

I need a view based on the office table that looks like this:

| office_id | docid1 | docid2 | docid3 | street | postcode | city |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 61 | 62 | 63 | .. | .. | .. |

and a view based on the doctors table looking like this:

| doctor_id | office_id | doc_id | name | surname |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 72 | 6 | 61 | .. | .. |
| 73 | 6 | 62 | .. | .. |
| 74 | 6 | 63 | .. | .. |

### office view

This one is easy enough we take the office table as the basis for the view and simply add the following colums:

```
[office.id]*10+1 AS DocID1, [office.id]*10+2 AS DocID2, [office.id]*10+3 AS DocID3
```

### doctors view

this one required a bit of googling but i found [this](https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/threads/sequential-numbers-in-a-query.312520/) forum post (@June7 is that also you in that thread?)
so we take the doctors table as the basis and add the following column:

```
[Office_ID]*10+DCount("1","Doctors","office_ID= " & [Office_ID] & " AND Doctors.ID <= " & [Doctors.ID]) AS DocID
```

This gives us the desired Doc ID and we can now create a third view based on these 2 where we add the doctors view 3 times and join it each time with docID1, docID2, docID3 respectively and each time add name and surname.

### conclusion

It is possible to recreate the old table without using VBA and solely relying on built in functions and SQL. I expect this to be a reasonable fast way to achieve this although i haven't measured it.

I welcome comments and improvements but I am now reasonably happy with the result.

Thanks for your input.

Comment: Thank you for that information. I tried to use only built in functions for the construction of the query and avoid VBA. Are the columns like [office_id]*10+1 or the one using DCount-function already considered user defined functions? If so what is problematic with DDE? I am more proficient in building queries and very rarely encounter set up complex mailmerge documents with field-functions. Thats why a query solution came to me first.

Comment: The MailMerge works fine now. It has no issues with the query, my only concern is that it will still expand the .accdb file to unreasonable size, but that i can check.

Answer (score 0):

For your original layout, the possibility of more than one entry could have been handled seamlessly via standard field coding in the mailmerge main document. For example:

```
Dear Dr {MERGEFIELD name1 \f " "}{MERGEFIELD surname1}{IF{MERGEFIELD surname2}<> "" "¶
"}{MERGEFIELD name2 \f " "}{MERGEFIELD surname2}{IF{MERGEFIELD surname3}<> "" "¶
"}{MERGEFIELD name3 \f " "}{MERGEFIELD surname3}¶
{MERGEFIELD office} {MERGEFIELD number} {MERGEFIELD street}¶
{MERGEFIELD city} {MERGEFIELD postcode}
```

For your 1:n relationship layout, you could save yourself a lot of effort and use Word's DATABASE field in conjunction with your mailmerge. For example, assuming you have a table of office_ids, with the addresses in that table:

```
Dear Dr {DATABASE \d "Filepath/MyDatabase.accdb" \s " SELECT [Name]&' '&[Surname] AS `Addressee` FROM [Doctors$] WHERE [office_id] = {MERGEFIELD ID}"}¶
{MERGEFIELD office} {MERGEFIELD number} {MERGEFIELD street}¶
{MERGEFIELD city} {MERGEFIELD postcode}
```

**Note:** The field brace pairs (i.e. '{ }') for the above examples are all created in the mailmerge main document itself, via Ctrl-F9 (Cmd-F9 on a Mac); you can't simply type them or copy & paste them from here. Nor is it practicable (for the most part) to add them via the standard Word dialogues. The spaces shown in the field constructions are all required. Instead of the ¶ symbols shown in the examples, you should use real line/paragraph breaks.

For more details, plus links to practical examples, see:

https://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/21803-mailmerge-tips-tricks.html

https://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/38721-microsoft-word-catalogue-directory-mailmerge-tutorial.html

Comment: Thank you for your effort. Your first version is the one implemented in the document and has been working for some time now. I will give your 2nd suggestion a try.

Comment: I used the database field as you described and read the description [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/field-codes-database-field-04398159-a2c9-463f-bb59-558a87badcbc) I managed to get the data into the document as a table but i would need to format a good looking addressfield from that. I haven't found the relevant section in your tips and tricks which would help me do that. @macropod

Comment: The info in the link isn't intended to cover every possible scenario. Some investment of your own effort to tailor the output to your own needs is expected. I note that your own posts say nothing specific of the expected output format. The DATABASE field has many optional output table formatting parameters you might explore. Some of these are employed in the links from the tutorial page.

Comment: I am sorry if you got the impression that I am not willing to invest enough of my own effort into your proposition. While I am interested in the possibility of using the fields in word to solve the problem, since I have a working solution based on an adjusted query I can only allow myself so much time to follow my professional curiousity. I am sorry if this came across as laziness.  I didn't specify the expected output format, I thought by talking about a letter, we have reasonably common understanding how the adress  is formatted.

Comment: I checked the table formatting options and they don' seem sufficient because it will always remain a table. Apart from Surname and Name I have also the fields [Title] and [Salutation] in the doctors tabel. I ommitted this for clarities sake but this will return a 4 Column table in the adress field, which my users would not accept. If there is a way to break up the table format I am interested in hearing but I have taken enough of you time already and I appreciate that. @macropod

Comment: All of those fields can be combined into a single column, if desired. My answer already shows how to do that for the Name & Surname fields. Naturally, the various records will remain on separate rows, however.